# app-psql not working properly? (Using Postgres Alpine container in docker)

Tags: postgresql, docker, database-connection, psql, docker-exec

I want to make a command to grant a user in a Postgresql running container certain privileges from command line, without having to access psql manually inside the container.
To do this you can use the app commands, here is the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/app-psql.html
(I've already used other app-commands successfully, for example to create databases with "docker exec -it samplePostgres createdb --username=root --owner=root --encoding=UTF8 sampleDB")

however when using:

```
docker exec -it samplePSQL psql -d sampleDB -c GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON table TO user;
```

It outputs the following

```
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "INSERT," ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "UPDATE" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "ON" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "table" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "TO" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "user" ignored
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: 
FATAL:  role "SELECT," does not exist
```

it somehow considers "SELECT" as the user??

of course running it from psql inside the container works like normal.

```
sampleDB=# GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON table TO user;
```

GRANT

Comment: Don't use comma's in your statement and put the entire statement between double quotes ".  And use the manual from a supported version, version 8.1 is unsupported for 11 years... Hard to believe you would use such an outdated version.

Comment: This is a shell issue.  The argument to `-c` is just the word "GRANT"  Everything after that are jut more command line arguments.  The first of which are interpreted as the username.  If you want to make the whole command string interpreted as one token, you need to put it in quotes to protect the spaces.